# Cómo mostrar dirección IP en el bashrc?

Tags: bash

Tengo esto en mi bashrc lo cual me permite ver mi dirección IP:

```
ipaddr=$(ip addr show eth0 | grep "inet\b" | awk '{print $2}'| cut -d/ -f1)
```

Pero el verdadero problema es que me gustaría que se fuera actualizando cada vez que presiono 'Enter'. Si pudiesen ayudarme con el código estaría agradecido

Comment: "Me gustaría que se fuera actualizando cada vez que presiono Enter": ¿la IP?

Comment: ¿Tu IP local cambia? ¿No te es mas conveniente usar IP fija?